# ms access 2010 expression containing empty fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

On an invoice form, I have a field that is a calculation of sums of my 2 subforms. One subform contains products prices and amount. Second subform contains line items such a discount, packaging etc. However, The second form is sometimes empty (no records for particular invoice).

**Problem**: The calculated field does not show any result, if second form is completely empty. Using "iif fieldvalue = Null" does not help. How to overcome this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to put the field inside Nz function.